# Why won't my simple C++ console app see my simple C++ static library headers in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, console-application, static-libraries

I followed the steps here to create a simple C++ static class library in Visual Studio 2015 and a C++ console app that uses the class library.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

Everything worked perfectly.

(I called my header ScottyMathFuncs.h)

Then I tried adding a second class to the static library and it complied fine but the console application won't see the new header file for the second class.
I tried deleting the original class and adding a new second class, which all complies fine in the static library project, but the console application won't see either of the new header files, and still sees and complies with the old header file that no longer exists.  It makes no sense.

Here is some screen shots of the current solution that is not working:

VS 2015 Solution showing CPlusPlusConsoleApp project and CPlusPlusStaticLib project, with the console app cpp and the two class header and cpp files highlighted:
[image: VS Solution]

Console Application Project Properties showing Path to Static defined in Additional Include Directory:
[image: Console App Project Properties]

Here is the Reference to the Static Lib I added to the Console Application Project:
[image: Console App Ref]

Here is a pic of the Console Application cpp where I am attempting to define the include for the new header files MyMathFuncs.h or MyMathFuncs2.h from the static library, but as you can see it only shows the old class that no longer exists.
[image: Console App Include]

I commented out the rest of the code in the console app that was so it would build.  You can see from the build output at the bottom that even if I just type 
MyMathFuncs.h regardless of that fact that intellisense doesn't see it, the build fails saying it can't find the header.

Here is the MyMathsFuncs.h:
[image: MyMathsFuncs Header]

Here is MyMathsFuncs.cpp:
[image: MyMathsFuncs CPP]

Here is MyMathsFuncs2.h:
[image: MyMathsFuncs2 Header]

Here is MyMathsFuncs2.cpp:
[image: MyMathsFuncs2 CPP]

In the process of re-documenting the issue, I actually just found the cause of the problem and fixed it. See the accepted answer.

Comment: It's called "static library" because you link with it *statically*, i.e. it pulls in all code from the library when linking, so you don't need to distribute a *dynamic* library (i.e. a DLL). On the downsides, linking statically, means your program will be larger, and a DLL can be shared by multiple programs and loaded programatically.

Comment: Joachim,  Thanks for the response mate... that answered that part of the question.  Much appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the process of doing such detailed documentation of the problem I found the cause of the issue!!

I had originally created the static lib project in the wrong location, so I removed it from the project and then copied it to another location (the same dir as the solution) and the added the existing project at the new location back into the solution.  The problem was that the reference in the console application was still pointing to the original copy of the project no longer linked to the solution, and this is why my console app was not aware of changes I was making to the project linked to the solution.

Maybe this will help someone else.....